# How to do Linear Mixed Effect Model in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have been trying to find out some packages and codes to realize the Linear Mixed Effect Model, but I failed. Does anyone know how to realize this?

Comment: Hi welcome to MMaSE! The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
1. A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal. 
2. A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
3. An example of what you expect as output. 
4. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
5. **Minimum due diligence**: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: Possibly related [Wolfram community thread](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/143183) but it is 9 years old.

Comment: There is no dedicated function to analyze linear mixed models as of version 13.1.  A somewhat simplified definition is that linear mixed models are regression models with more than one error term.  You can perform such analyses using the `LogLikelihood` function but that can take a lot of work.  You're best best is to use R directly or call R from within *Mathematica*.  I understand why Wolfram might be reluctant to provide such functionality because getting convergence can be a big problem especially with small sample sizes and/or mis-specified models.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'll try.